# div F=0 iff F=curl G?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F$ be the curl of some vector field $G$. Assuming that all the mixed partial derivatives are continuous, by the Jacobian matrix of the curl $G$, the matrix $DF$, we find that $tr(DF) = 0$, which shows that div $F$ = div (curl $G$) = 0. So we conclude that  div $F$ = 0 is a necessary condition to $F$ be the curl of some vector field $G$.

Now consider a divergence such that div $F$ = 0. Does it follow that $F$ is the curl of some vector field $G$? Is the condition div $F$ = 0 sufficient to argue that $F$ is the curl of some $G$?

Comment: What is the domain of the vector fields and what space are you considering?

Comment: hm, this is a question to consider before answering mine. And if we consider 3d space without any voids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've find out a counter example which shows that if div $F$ = 0 it does not follow that $F$ is the curl of some $G$.

Just take $F(x,y,z) = (||r||^{-3}x,||r||^{-3}y,||r||^{-3}z)$, where $ r=(x,y,z).$ It is easy to verify that div $F$ = 0. Assuming that F is the curl of some G in a region which contains the origin, we can show that $\int\int $(curl $G \cdot n)dS$ $\neq \int G \cdot d\alpha$, which is an absurd by Stoke's theorem.

Comment: You vector field is singular at the origin. There are two ways to consider this: either the divergence is a delta function, so not identically zero, or the vector field is only defined on $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$, contradicting your assumption that the domain has no holes.

Comment: i've edited it :)

Comment: That doesn't address my comment, because $F$ is still defined on a region that has a hole.